# how to underclock an nvidia GPU on Windows?

Tags: windows, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

i wanted to know if there exist a software that can do that?
my card is `nvidia 7600GT`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [NVIDIA nTune](http://www.nvidia.com/object/ntune_5.05.54.00.html) :

> NVIDIA® nTune is the ultimate utility
>   for accessing, monitoring, and
>   adjusting your system components,
>   including temperature and voltages
>   with clear, user-friendly control
>   panels. Overclock your system for
>   highest performance or underclock it
>   for near silent operation. All changes
>   are performed within the Microsoft®
>   Windows® interface – enabling full
>   functionality without the need to make
>   changes in the BIOS and reboot your
>   system.

Comment: it works fine but the problem is that after the reboot the frequencies arent saved. is there is a way to save the frequency between reboots?

Comment: Don't use that version of nTune. That is the nTune tool from 2007. Even google points to the old one.   nVidia has a more recent release of nTune, packaged as "nVidia System Tools", at: http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia_system_tools_6.06.html , from April 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner) to [overclock or underclock](http://www.guru3d.com/article/rivatuner-20-fan-speed--overclock-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [nvidiaInspector](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/nvidia-inspector-download.html), because it has a great overview about the most important sensor data and a clean, minimalistic interface. Also you can create desktop shortcuts for different Profiles for fast switching between configurations.